# how to access usb in racket?

Tags: usb, racket

which lib contain usb function?
I am looking for a racket lib like the pyserial lib in python.
how to write Serial communications application in racket?

Comment: Which programming language do you want to use?

Comment: Best to ask on the [mailing list](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/).  This subject came up [last month](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2011-December/049723.html).  (If you're the one who asked, then you can try to post again...)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there a library specifically written in racket for reading/writing to serial ports, however, you can read/write to character devices using standard i/o routines.